# How to take a line of text and take out all comments, empty lines, extra whitespaces, and info in the parenthesis?

Tags: java, printwriter

This project requires me to read a file in process it by taking out all comments, empty lines, extra whitespaces, and info in the parenthesis and then print it into output.txt.  I have had trouble processing the data and taking out all of the comments, empty lines, extra whitespaces, and info in the parenthesis.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/*
 * @author wrigh4d
 * Date: 11/7/19
 * Description:  Takes instruction from SumN and then prints it into output.txt 
 */

public class InstructionExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Sets up Scanner/Print Writer and declares variable
        File myFile = new File("sumN.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

        String currentLine = "";

        //Sets up while loop to read in each line
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            currentLine = sc.nextLine();    //Sets each line to currentLine
            currentLine = processLine(currentLine); //Takes currentLine down to processLine
            if(currentLine != "") { //if there is something inside of current Line it appends it to printwriter
                pw.append(currentLine + "\n");
            }

        }

        pw.flush(); //prints onto output.txt

    }

    public static String processLine(String currentLine) {
        //Gets rid of whitespace inside of currentLine
        String a = currentLine.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println(a);

        return a;

    }

}
```

Here is SumN:

```
// Adds 1+...+100.
//initialize variable i and sum
@i // i refers to some mem. location.
M=1 // i=1
@sum // sum refers to some mem. location.
M=0 // sum=0

//the loop to sum
(LOOP)  //the LOOP label
@i
D=M // D=i
@100
D=D-A // D=i-100
@END
D;JGT // If (i-100)>0 goto END
@i
D=M // D=i
@sum
M=D+M // sum=sum+i
@i
M=M+1 // i=i+1
@LOOP
0;JMP // Goto LOOP

//Terminate the program
(END)
@END
0;JMP // Infinite loop
```

Comment: You basically need a parser.  You might be able to get by with `String.split()` and some logic.

Comment: You could avoid comments in your code which repeat the obvious like `Object a = new Object(); // create new object with name a`

Comment: Then, what's precisely the trouble you have? Have you considered to operate character-wise rather than token/line-wise, e.g. like shown [here](http://candidjava.com/tutorial/program-to-read-a-file-character-by-character/)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [Regex Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match the things you want to take out:

```
public static String processLine(String currentLine) {
    // Gets rid of whitespace inside of currentLine
    String a = currentLine.replaceAll("//.+|\\s|\\(.+", "");
    System.out.println(a);

    return a;
}
```

Also evaluate the *currentLine* with isEmpty() function, instead of != "":

```
// Sets up while loop to read in each line
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    currentLine = sc.nextLine(); // Sets each line to currentLine
    currentLine = processLine(currentLine); // Takes currentLine down to processLine
        if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) { // if there is something inside of current Line it appends it to printwriter
            pw.append(currentLine + "\n");
    }
}
```